# How to keep global variable unchanged in js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

It's a Chrome Extension JS, i want to compare the DOM tree structure between DOM loaded and all these files loaded.Here I declare two variable first and then it will run into these 2 Listeners. But txt1 won't keep the value in the 1st listener, no matter declare it with var or window. So how can I keep the global value? Or can I bypass it in other ways?

```
    function tw1(){ 
    var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(document,NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT,{ acceptNode: function(node) { return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT; } },false);

    var ar = new Array();
    var count=0;
    while(treeWalker.nextNode()) {
    ar[count]=treeWalker.currentNode.nodeName;
    count++;
    console.log(treeWalker.currentNode.nodeName);

    }

    var txt="";
    for (var i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
    txt=txt+ar[i]+i+"\t";
    }
    //console.log(txt); 
    return txt; 

    }

    function compare(str,str0)
        { 
         if(str.indexOf(str0) == 0&& str0.indexOf(str) == 0)
         {
          return 0;
         }
         else
         {
          return 1;
         }
    }

    window.txt1="";
    window.txt2="";

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        window.txt1=tw1();

    }, false);

    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        window.txt2=tw1();
        console.log(window.txt1);
        console.log(window.txt2);
        if(compare(window.txt1,window.txt2)!=0)
            alert("This page is possibly malicious.");

    }, false);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "keep the global value"? Do you want it to stay an empty string? Also, where are you defining `tw1`?

Comment: @Asad tw1() is a function traversing DOM tree and returns a String, I put it before these codes. In the 2nd Listener, txt1 is "", though it was a long String when the 1st listener executed.

Comment: @user1261718: Post *all* of your code.

Comment: @Blender Edited, it's the whole contentscript file.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest is adding a check condition

```
if(!window.txt1.length)
    window.txt1=tw1();
```

Comment: when i checked console.log() in the first listener, txt1 is assigned a value, while when it comes into the 2nd listener, txt1 goes back to "" as defined at first. I checked some value-passing between 2 fuctions, like using window. , but it won't let txt1 in 2nd listener keep the value while in the 1st listener.

Comment: @Sushanth-- do you mean if(!window.txt1.length)

Comment: @Sushanth I made a mistake, first tw1 returns nothing... i mistook the tw1 in 2nd listener's output for the 1st listener... gonna edit it